# Exposing a subset of a Java object to JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

We have a front-end service that uses a back-end service to get a list of Metric objects. We've written a Java ClientSDK for the back-end service to make life easier for development of client applications of that service.

We also expose a list of Metrics from the front-end service. For now, we're directly exposing and converting the back-end Metric objects to JSON.

My concern is that if changes are made to the back-end Metric object - say a developer adds a new secret ID field - we don't want to expose it from the front-end service.

We're also writing a clientSDK for the front-end service. We don't want to reference the Metric class from the back-end clientSDK, so the logical option is to define a similar Metric object in the front-end SDK.

I don't want to waste CPU cycles copying 1000's of Metrics from one class definition to another.

Is there a way to specify which fields I should expose from the back-end Metric to the front-end definition of Metric as I'm converting to JSON? Better yet, can I reference the front-end definition to the JSON converter as I ask it to marshal the back-end object?

We're using Jackson with the Spring rest framework for context, but I'd be happy to drop that in a heartbeat since marshaling objects via annotations seems to be the root cause of this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Jackson's JsonView](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) construct.

I can see your example looking something like this:

```
class Views {
    static class Client {}
    static class Backend extends Client {}
}

public class Metric {
    @JsonView(Views.Client.class) String metricName;
    @JsonView(Views.Client.class) String count;
    @JsonView(Views.Backend.class) String secretKey;
}
```

The `@JsonView` annotation is supported on Spring `@ResponseBody` annotated methods as of [Spring 4.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.1.html#_web_improvements).

Comment: There is also a `@JsonIgnore` annotation, which depending on the OP's exact setting might be the easier choice.

Answer (score 0):

As [Nicholas Hausschild](https://stackoverflow.com/users/343568/nicholas-hauschild) has suggested you can achieve this by annotations with your marshalling/unmarshalling framework.

However you can simply use inheritance and casting like this:

```
class SomeSuperClass {
  String exposeThis;
  String exposeThat;
  // getters and setters...
}

class SomeSubClass extends SomeSuperClass {
  String doNotExposeThis;
  // getters and setters...
}
```

This way you can cast to the super class when returning an object to the JSON parser, and at the same time use the subclass internally to carry additional information which you don't really want to expose.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is the use of `Mixins`, so you can define different scenarios without touching the original `DTO`.

I myself use a library I wrote to achieve this dynamically:

https://github.com/Antibrumm/jackson-antpathfilter

This works well for not too deep graphs, else someone wrote another approach in a similar way here which seems more performant for these scenarios, but behaves a bit different.

https://github.com/krishna81m/jackson-nested-prop-filter